# getting an error while trying to fetch a data from a bearer token in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api, bearer-token

im getting this weird error in console.log while trying to fetch data from a bearer token API

```
dispatchSetState(fiber, queue, action) {
      {
        if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
          error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'sec…
```

after trying to fetch the data from a Bearer token API using Reactjs.

here is my code:

```
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://myapi.com/api/products", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResult(json));
    console.log(setResult);
  }, []);
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not an error, you need to `console.log(result)` in outside of `useEffect` not  `console.log(setResult);`,

Comment: thank u for u answer it kinda works
but it kept giving me the same result above the data

Comment: did you console.log(result) and still get the same error?

Comment: You need to remove console.log(setResult);

Comment: i removed it and put it outside useEffect because i need to check the result

Comment: yes but now console.log(result) check
You have confused setResult and result. useState returns the current state and a function that updates it. The first one "result" is the state and the second one setResult is the function no need to console that.